# Mismatch during if-statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am slowly learning VBA here and I seem to be running into a mismatch problem. The goal is to find the row that I am working on i.e "Current" and then autofill the information on the second sheet in specific cells. From using the debugger, the issue seems to be inside the if-statement. Any help is appreciated!

I tried to go through and change the cell type in the sheet itself. Also tried using .Range instead of .Cells (assuming I am even doing that correctly.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Integer, LastRow

'Find the last row in the Information sheet
'LastRow = Sheets("Information").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To 1000 'Check rows 3 through the last one

    If Sheets("Information").Cells("A", i).Value = "Current" Then 'Check what row has current
        Sheets("Scorecard").Range("B3") = Sheets("Information").Cells("A" & i) 'Input the name in the scorecard

        End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

Error states

```
Run-time error '13'
Type Mismatch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Sheets("Information").Cells("A", i).Value = "Current" Then
```

should be

```
If Sheets("Information").Cells(i, "A").Value = "Current" Then
```

Similarly:

```
Sheets("Information").Cells("A" & i) >> Sheets("Information").Cells(i, "A")
```

Comment: This ended up fixing my Mismatch error, now however, it is not entering the if statement even though the statement is true on one account. Do I need to set the cell to be a specific type i.e. text?

Comment: Are you sure there are no extra spaces around the value?

Comment: Yes, I just went and confirmed.

Comment: OK then it's something else but I've no idea what - if the `If` statement is not getting triggered then it's difficult to say why without access to the worksheet.

Comment: Are you actually entering "Current" into that cell, or is it maybe formatted to display that?   In which case try `Cells(i, "A").Text` instead

Comment: It is manually put into the cell. But that fixed it there, I also put the cell type as text. Thank you! Everything works now.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have checked for possible null values, then you want to get/set the value of the Cell, not the Cell itself:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Integer, LastRow

'Find the last row in the Information sheet
'LastRow = Sheets("Information").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To 1000 'Check rows 3 through the last one

    If Sheets("Information").Cells("A", i).Value = "Current" Then 'Check what row has current
        Sheets("Scorecard").Range("B3").value = Sheets("Information").Cells("A" & i).value 'Input the name in the scorecard

        End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: To note - Range.value is not needed

Comment: noted, I guess null values is the only possible reason then?

Comment: I think the cells.value is probably needed though